# Mathematical expression from Fortran code

Tags: math, fortran

I would like to describe this statement (written in Fortran) in order to compute a PDFs of the eigenvalue `srevals(1:3)` using a (numerics) mathematics description (LaTeX)

```
integer,parameter::eigenbins=100
integer,parameter::npdims=3
real,dimension(npdim)::srevals
real,dimension(eigenbins,npdim)::srevalspdf 
real::ray,hray 
integer::io,w

ray=20E-4
hray=ray/2
DO io=1,npdim
  DO w=1,eigenbin
    IF (       srevals(io) .GT. real(w-1)*ray/real(eigenbins)-hray &
       & .and. srevals(io) .LE. real(w  )*ray/real(eigenbins)-hray ) THEN
      srevalspdf(w,io)=srevalspdf(w,io)+1
      EXIT
    ENDIF
  ENDDO
ENDDO
```

How can I describe this using just latex and some sentences?

Comment: We do not know what the entities in the code are. We do not even know how the are declared. But this is not just some simple equation. You will likely need pseudo-code that basically does the same as the code in Fortran.

Comment: This is still pretty unclear because for a mathematical description one needs to know what those entities are mathematically. Normally one has the mathematics first and then implements the code. The other way is strange but this certainly does not look like something for a mathematical expression. Rather something, that will need to rewrite the algorithm in a pseudocode pretty much literally.

Comment: To add to the previous comments, it is impossible to look at some individual lines of a larger program and be sure to know what they do. The entire context of a program unit (and possibly even more) is required. For example, if `eigenbin` has (unshown) value less than 1 then the answer is "nothing exciting happens". Maybe there's an `external real` somewhere you haven't shown. Or maybe `ray` is a NaN.

Comment: @veryreverie You don't have the access to reopen queues yet, but if you think the question can be answered now, we can vote to reopen it. Still, the OP probably expects more than just simplified Fortran code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N.B. I'm assuming you have typos in your question, and that `eigenbin` and `eigenbins` are meant to be the same, and that `npdim` and `npdims` are meant to be the same.

### Simplified code

The first thing to note is that the body of your `if` condition (in maths not Fortran) is

```
(w-1)*ray/eigenbins - ray/2 < srevals(io) <= w*ray/eigenbins - ray/2
```

Since `ray` and `eigenbins` are positive, we can rearrange this to give

```
w-1 < eigenbins*(srevals(io)/ray+0.5) <= w
```

and this can only be true if

```
w = ceiling(eigenbins*(srevals(io)/ray+0.5))
```

This means you can replace the double loop

```
DO io=1,npdim
  DO w=1,eigenbin
    IF (       srevals(io) .GT. real(w-1)*ray/real(eigenbins)-hray &
       & .and. srevals(io) .LE. real(w  )*ray/real(eigenbins)-hray ) THEN
      srevalspdf(w,io)=srevalspdf(w,io)+1
      EXIT
    ENDIF
  ENDDO
ENDDO
```

with the single loop

```
DO io=1,npdim
  w = ceiling(eigenbins*(srevals(io)/ray+0.5))
  if (1 <= w .and. w <= eigenbins) then
    srevalspdf(w,io) = srevalspdf(w,io) + 1
  endif
ENDDO
```

### Physical meaning

If `srevals` is an array of eigenvalues, and you have `eigenbins` evenly spaced bins between `-ray/2` and `ray/2` into which you want to group these eigenvalues, then this code creates the array `srevalspdf` which records which bin each eigenvalue falls in. Assuming you have zeroed `srevalspdf` before this code, `srevalspdf(w,io)` will be `1` if eigenvalue `io` is in bin `w`, and `0` otherwise.

Comment: Why is the single loop independent of `eigenbin` unlike the original?